# Perl: Named parameters validation best practice

Tags: perl, validation, parameters, named

I am using named parameters in class method calls and was wondering if there is a best practice to make sure no unknown parameters are passed. Here's what I am doing

```
sub classmethod {
    my $self = shift;
    my %args = (
        "param1" => "default1",
        "param2" => "default2",
        @_
    )

    if (my @invalid = grep { !/^(param1|param2)$/ } keys %args) {
        croak "received unknown arg(s) ".join(",", @invalid)." from ".caller();
    }
}
```

Is that a proper way to go forward, or could this cause a performance problem?

Best,
Marcus

Answer (score 5):

You could use [Params::Validate](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/Params-Validate-1.08/lib/Params/Validate.pm). Another option is [Params::Check](http://search.cpan.org/~bingos/Params-Check-0.38/lib/Params/Check.pm)

If params are fixed, then its best to validate them during development, with the option to turn off validation when live.

Comment: I've voted this up as both modules seem to be useful to validate parameters. I will not make this an accepted answer though as it seems to be a bit of an overkill to use another module just to check for unwanted terms. Anyway, thanks for the effort!

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to pass parameters in Perl, and a lot of ways to validate them (or not).

If you are using the explicit default idiom anyway and want a light touch, then you can check that the number of keys in the hash are equal to the number of keys in the defaults. Getting the number of keys is a fast operation that doesn't depend on the size or contents of the hash table. If there is a key "in" `@_` that isn't in `%default`, then `%args` will have more keys.

The disadvantage that this has over your current solution is that it doesn't tell you which key is unexpected.

```
sub classmethod {
    my $self = shift;
    my %args = (
        param1 => "default1",
        param2 => "default2",
        @_
    );
    keys %args == 2 or croak "received unknown arg. args: " . join(", ", keys %args);
}
```

Or do something like this to avoid having to change the number when you change the number of parameters.

```
sub classmethod {
    my $self = shift;
    my %default = (
        param1 => "default1",
        param2 => "default2",
    );
    my %args = (%default, @_);

    keys %args == keys %default or croak 'unknown arg' . join(", ", keys %args);
}
```

Comment: See also [How to specify default values for optional subroutine arguments?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29577085/2173773)