# How to specify default values for optional subroutine arguments?

Tags: perl

Is there an elegant way to specify default values for subroutine arguments?

Currently, I am using the following approach:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

func1( "arg1", "arg2", opt1 => "first option", opt2 => 0 );

sub func1 {
    my ( $arg1, $arg2, %opt ) = @_;

    $opt{opt1} //= "no option";
    $opt{opt2} //= 1;
    $opt{opt3} //= [];
}
```

which looks a little bit ugly, when there are many options. I would rather like to do

```
sub func2 {
    my ( $arg1, $arg2, $opt ) = process_args( 
        opt1 => "no option", opt2 => 1, opt3 => []
    );
}
```

The best I could come up with for this approach was:

```
sub func2 {
    my ( $arg1, $arg2, $opt ) = process_args(
        \@_, 2, opt1 => "no option", opt2 => 1, opt3 => []
    );
}

sub process_args {
    my ($a, $n, %opt_info ) = @_;

    my @b = splice @$a, 0, $n;
    my %opt = @$a;
    for my $key (keys %opt_info) {
        $opt{$key} //= $opt_info{$key};
    }
    return (@b, \%opt);
}
```

but now I got the other problem, that I must pass `\@_` and the number of non-option arguments ( here 2 ), to `process_args`..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sub func1 {
    my $arg1 = shift;
    my $arg2 = shift;
    my %opt = (
       opt1 => 'default',
       opt2 => 'default',
       @_
    );
```

Or, you can use [Params::Validate](https://metacpan.org/pod/Params::Validate).

Comment: Thanks, Param::Validate seems like the best solution!

Answer (score 3):

I don't remember seeing a subroutine written expressly to handle subroutine parameters. Do you have a Ruby background?

You can define the options hash by a list of its defaults, followed by anything passed in `@_`. Like this

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

func1( "arg1", "arg2", opt1 => "first option", opt2 => 0 );

sub func1 {
  my ( $arg1, $arg2 ) = splice @_, 0, 2;
  my %opts = (
    opt1 => "no option",
    opt2 => 1,
    opt3 => [],
    @_,
  );
}
```

Another mechanism, if you want to warn against unsupported paremeters, is to do much as you have, but use `delete`, and to ensure that the hash is empty afterwards, like this

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dump;
use Carp 'croak';

func1( "arg1", "arg2", opt9 => 9 );

sub func1 {
  my ( $arg1, $arg2, %opt ) = @_;

  my $opt1 = delete $opt{opt1} // 'no option';
  my $opt2 = delete $opt{opt2} // 1;
  my $opt3 = delete $opt{opt3} // [];

  croak "Unexpected parameters: ", join ',', keys %opt if keys %opt;
}
```

**output**

```
Unexpected parameters: opt9 at E:\Perl\source\args.pl line 16.
  main::func1("arg1", "arg2", "opt9", 9) called at E:\Perl\source\args.pl line 7
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on handling unexpected parameters!

Comment: Of course, `Carp::croak` would be much more useful than `die` especially with this type of error.

Comment: @SinanÜnür: I was in two minds about `croak`, and omitted it because the subroutine isn't in a separate module, and because it isn't central to the question. However, in retrospect, the whole concept of reporting unexpected arguments is non-essential anyway and you have changed my mind. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
# isolate the default options
{
  my %default_options = (
    opt1 => 'default for opt1',
    opt2 => 'default for opt2',
  );

  sub func1 {
    my $arg1 = shift @_;
    my $arg2 = shift @_;

    # set options
    my %opt  = %default_options;
    if( my %given_opts = @_ ){
      for my $key ( keys %opt ){
        if( exists $given_opts{$key} ){
          $opt{$key} = $given_opts{$key};
        }
      }
    }

    # rest of func1
  }
}
```