# In perl, can I dynamically create variables within a subroutine?

Tags: perl

## Background

In the code I'm writing, I'm passing data into methods using a hash-ref (see note [1]).

This, unfortunately, leads to a lot of repetitive code:

```
sub thing {
  my ($self, $params) = @_;

  my ($foo, $bar, $baz, $biff,);
  if ( exists $params->{foo} && $params->{foo} ) {
     $foo = $params->{foo};
  }
  # repeat for `bar`, `baz`, `biff`

  ## rest of function ##
}
```

(and duplicate in every function with parameters)

## What I want to do

What would be far easier is to define a list of parameters, and then
iterate of that list, creating both the variables and setting them to a value if needed.

So to test this, I tried:

```
my $params = { x => 1, y => 2};
my @params = qw(x y z a b c);

gno strict 'refs';
rep( ${$_}, @params );
use strict 'refs';

foreach my $p (@params) {
  if ( exists $params->{$p} && $params->{$p} ) {
    ${$p} = $params->{$p};
  }
}
print "x:$x, y:$y, z:$z, a:$a, b:$b, c:$c\n"
```

which gives me the following error:

```
Global symbol "$x" requires explicit package name at ./test.pl line 20.
Global symbol "$y" requires explicit package name at ./test.pl line 20.
Global symbol "$z" requires explicit package name at ./test.pl line 20.
Global symbol "$c" requires explicit package name at ./test.pl line 20.
```

Can I do this dynamic variable creation thing?  (and if so, how?)

---

[1] By using a hash to pass data in, I gain in many ways:

1. There is a clear indication of What each item of data is
2. The ORDER of the pieces of data is no longer important
3. I can miss one or more pieces of data, and I don't need to add in random `undef` values
4. I'm passing less data: 1 scalar (a reference) rather than multiple scalars
5. (I accept the danger of functions being able to change the parent's data, rather that mucking around with a copy of it...)

Comment: Those are warnings, you have not declared variables $x, $y, $z, $c.

Comment: @serenesat - I know.... those are the variables I'm trying to dynamically create from the `@params` list

Comment: See also [How to specify default values for optional subroutine arguments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29577085/how-to-specify-default-values-for-optional-subroutine-arguments)

Comment: @HåkonHægland The Validate::Params thing is nice.... but one still needs to create a list of variables, and then iterate over each possible parameter to [possibly] set the scalar value...

Comment: Yes, but why not just keep the parameters in `$params`? If you need to use one, for example `foo`, you can write (as an example) `my $result = $params->{foo} + 2`.. Then it might be easier to read your code later? As it is clear that you are using a parameter..

Comment: http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do this in Perl. But it's a terrible idea for all of the reasons explained by Mark Dominus in [these](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html) [three](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname2.html) [articles](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname3.html).

It's a far better idea to store these values in a hash.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $params = { x => 1, y => 2};
my @params = qw(x y z a b c);

my %var;

foreach my $p (@params) {

  # You need to take care exactly what you want in this
  # logical statement. The options are:
  # 1/ $p exists in the hash
  #    exists $params->{$p}
  # 2/ $p exists in the hash and has a defined value
  #    defined $params->{$p}
  # 3/ $p exists in the hash and has a true value
  #    $params->{$p}
  # I think the first option is most likely. The last one has
  # good chance of introducing subtle bugs.

  if ( exists $params->{$p} ) {
    $var{$p} = $params->{$p};
  }
}

print join ', ', map { "$_: " . ($var{$_} // 'undef') } @params;
print "\n";
```

Comment: Note that `&& $params->{$p}` will skip any untrue value (zero, empty string etc), which may or may not be what one wants.

Comment: Bugger. Yes, I spotted that as I was writing my answer, but forgot to fix it. Updated answer to clarify.

Comment: Yah - but `if ( exists $params->{$p} && defined $params->{$p} )` will fix that (and, incidental, my own bad code)

Answer (score 2):

It's a really bad idea to use symbolic references like this... hashes pretty well completely eliminate the need for this.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $params = { x => 1, y => 2, foo => 3, };

thing($params);

sub thing {
    my $params = shift;
    my $foo;
    if (defined $params->{foo}){
        $foo = $params->{foo};
    }
    print $foo;
}
```

You can also pass in a hash itself directly (whether it be pre-created, or passed inline to the sub. If pre-created, the sub will operate on a copy).

```
thing(foo => 1, x => 2);

sub thing {
    my %params = @_;
    print $params{foo} if defined $params{foo};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With thanks to Dave Cross & others - the following test works:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;
use English qw( -no_match_vars ) ;
use Carp;
use Data::Dumper;

my $params = { x => 1, y => 2, z => 0};
my @params = qw(x y z a b c);

my %var;

foreach my $p (@params) {
  if ( exists $params->{$p} ) {
    $var{$p} = $params->{$p};
  } else {
    $var{$p} = undef;
  }
}

print Dumper \%var;
```

This gives me `%var` with all desired parameters (as listed in `@params`, with the ones that are not passed in (ie, not in the `$params` hashref) created with an `undef` value.

Thus I can confidently test for *value* and *truth*, without worrying about *existence*.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

I did this using soft references:

```
#!perl

no strict "refs";

my %vars = ( x => 1, y => 2 );

for my $k ( keys %vars ) {
  $$k = $vars{$k};
}

print $x, $y;
```

But there's a reason why the recommended settings (use strict; use warnings;) prevent this kind of pattern. It is easy to shoot yourself in the foot with it.

Comment: Interesting....... however this leaves me without the existence of the optional parameters - which means I can't even do `if exists $foo`, let alone `if defined $foo`

(and yes - I appreciate the opportunities for "hole-in-foot" :)  )

Comment: You can still do `if exists $foo`. But using the above style of code, $foo can magically spring into life.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -Mstrict -MData::Dumper -wE'
  {package Data::Dumper;our($Indent,$Sortkeys,$Terse,$Useqq)=(1)x4}
  my @aok = qw( x  y  z  a  b  c );
  my %dft = ( a => -1 );
  say "- - - -";
  my $arg = { x => 1, y => 2, foo => 42 };
  $arg = { %dft, %$arg };
  say "arg: ", Dumper($arg);

  my %var;                     
  @var{ @aok } = @$arg{ @aok };
  say "var: ", Dumper(\%var);

  my %aok = map { $_ => 1 } @aok;
  my @huh = grep !$aok{$_}, sort keys %$arg;
  @huh and say "huh: ", Dumper(\@huh);
'
- - - -
arg: {
  "a" => -1,
  "foo" => 42,
  "x" => 1,
  "y" => 2
}

var: {
  "a" => -1,
  "b" => undef,
  "c" => undef,
  "x" => 1,
  "y" => 2,
  "z" => undef
}

huh: [
  "foo"
]
```

Comment: [If you add some comments to this, why it works, and what doesn't work in the original you can make this answer much better.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)